# How to add Date every day to my first blank row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like every day, when I open excel, that my excel would add a today's date to it. I have this code, but it isn't working, sometimes it does what it's supposed to and sometimes it skips a line, any help please?

```
Sub Stretching()
'This procedure will run each time you open the workbook

   'Specify the required worksheet name in double quotes
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Stretching")

    'Get the last row number filled with a value in Column A
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Check if the last entered date is the same as the current date, if so, exit
    'You need this check to see if you close the workbook then open it on the same day
    'so that the code does not enter the same date again in a new row.
    If ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Date Then Exit Sub

    'Fill a new row in Column A with the current date
    If IsEmpty(Cells(lastRow, 1)) Then
        ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Date
    Else
        ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't using the stretching sheet when checking ```isempty``` nor are you using it to find the lastrow. That might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions on your code:

1. Fully qualifying the ranges help you avoiding inconsistent results. This means, you can be running the procedure when an active sheet is different than the one you are targeting, and this line: `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` would return a different "last row" than the one you'd expect
2. Also try to use variable names that are easily understandable. For example, `ws` vs `targetSheet`

**Please try this code and let me know if it works:**

```
Public Sub Stretching()
    'This procedure will run each time you open the workbook

   'Specify the required worksheet name in double quotes
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stretching")

    'Get the last row number filled with a value in Column A
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Check if the last entered date is the same as the current date, if so, exit
    'You need this check to see if you close the workbook then open it on the same day
    'so that the code does not enter the same date again in a new row.
    If targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Date Then Exit Sub

    'Fill a new row in Column A with the current date
    If IsEmpty(targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1)) Then
        targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = Date
    Else
        targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer. I would also add that if this is something that will be run every day when first opening the Excel document, there's an argument to be made for migrating this code to a `Workbook_Open` statement. Only thing that changes is planning around multiple opens in a single day.